# Check if element has the class active, if so, add class to a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Building a website for a client but only for the mainpage I need to get a class on the main div for css purposes. For this I am trying to look for an active class on menu item for home, and if it has the active class, then add a different class to the main webpage's div.

so far i cant get much further then this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
if $('li.level1.item101').hasClass('active');
$('#main').addClass('woodwork');}
});
</script>
```

the html involved for this (the li item) looks like this when active with the div somewhere down below in the page itself

```
<li class="level1 item101 active current"> </li>
<li class="level1 item102"> </li>
<div id="main"> </div>
```

my current code doesn't seem to be able to grab either the active li or the div, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: div next to li?? that is invalid DOM.

Comment: Also you dont need to use .find() to get an id just use `$('#main')` since IDs must be unique

Comment: Your current code looks like it is invalid. Try writing an actual `if` statement with all the parenthesis, curlies: `if( ... ){ ... }`. You also don't want to do `addClass('.woodwork')` but `.addClass('woodwork')`

Comment: The div isn't next to the li, its nested in a ul and all that but if i'd post the whole html of the site we're building you get a huge list of unnecessary code. And ok thanks Anton :) i'll change that part, but it still wont add the new class to it with that change

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you have some errors with your code, the html should be:

```
<li class="level1 item101 active current"> active</li>
<li class="level1 item102"> second</li>
<div id="main"> main </div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ( $('li.level1.item101').hasClass('active') ) {
    $('#main').addClass('woodwork');
  }
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9ns4/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly, I was aware i had a few errors in it yes but couldn't figure it out where and what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="level1 item101 active current"> </li>
    <li class="level1 item102"> </li>
</ul>
<div id="main"> </div>
```

The JavaScript should look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('li.item101').hasClass('active'))
        $('#main').addClass('woodwork');
});
```

Here I just look if the Listelement with the class item101 has the class active, if it is so I give the div-Tag with the ID main the class woodwork