# Getting active label name in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following lines of code:

```
<div>                                                                       
    <label>Property type</label>                                            

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">       
        <div class="btn-group">                                             
            <label class="btn btn-default">                                 
                <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB            
            </label>                                                        
        </div>                                                              

        <div class="btn-group">                                             
            <label class="btn btn-default active">                          
                <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio">Condo / Apt    
            </label>                                                        
        </div>                                                              

        <div class="btn-group">                                             
            <label class="btn btn-default">                                 
                <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
            </label>                                                        
        </div>                                                              
    </div>                                                                  
</div>
```

**Now my question is:** How can i get the **name** of input tag which is highlighted as active in label (From JavaScript or JQuery).

**In above scenario answer should be:** SECOND

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element has the class active, if so, add class to a different element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630727/check-if-element-has-the-class-active-if-so-add-class-to-a-different-element)

Comment: Does the `<label>` with the class-name of `'active'` imply that the descendant `<input>` is also checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one active label :

```
$('.active').find('input').attr("name");
```

Thanks to JeetDaloneboy for providing this JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2prve7mo/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myname = $('.active').children('input').attr('name')
console.log(myname);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio">Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery the simplest option would be:

```
// find the <input> descendant of a <label> element 
// with the class-name of 'active':
var name = $('label.active input')
  // retrieve its 'name' property:
  .prop('name');

console.log(name); // 'SECOND'
```

```js
var name = $('label.active input').prop('name');

console.log(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio">Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If, however, there are multiple `<label>` elements with the class of `active`, the following is an alternative:

```
// using map() to form an array-like structure of
// formed from the collection:
var names = $('label.active input').map(function(){

  // returning the name property of each of the
  // found <input> elements:
  return this.name;

// using get() to turn the map into an Array:
}).get();

console.log(names); // ['SECOND', 'THIRD']
```

```js
var name = $('label.active input').map(function() {
  return this.name;
}).get();

console.log(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio">Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the 'active' class on the `<label>` implies that the `<input>` is itself checked, then an easier solution might be to select the checked `<input>` directly:

```
// finding the <input> element that is checked,
// and recovering its 'name' property:
var name = $('input:checked').prop('name');

console.log(name); // 'SECOND'
```

```js
var name = $('input:checked').prop('name');

console.log(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio" checked>Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, this is quite easily possible in plain JavaScript in much the same way:

```
// using document.querySelector() to retrieve the first, if any,
// element which matches the supplied CSS selector (finding
// an <input> element which is checked, and then retrieving the
// 'name' property from that element node:
var name = document.querySelector('input:checked').name;

console.log(name); // 'SECOND'
```

```js
var name = document.querySelector('input:checked').name;

console.log(name);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio" checked>Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As `document.querySelector()` will return `null` if there is no element matching the supplied selector it's worth checking the existence of a match before trying to retrieve the property:

```
// finding the first, if any, <input> element that is checked:
var checkedElement = document.querySelector('input:checked');

// if the checkedElement variable is truthy (not-null in this
// case):
if (checkedElement) {

  // we retrieve the value of the 'name' property from
  // the <input> element-node:
  var name = checkedElement.name;

  console.log(name); // 'SECOND'
}
```

```js
var checkedElement = document.querySelector('input:checked');

if (checkedElement) {
  var name = checkedElement.name;
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio" checked>Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, of course, it's possible to select the `<input>` via the existence of the `active` class-name on the parent `<label>` element with plain JavaScript:

```
// finding the first <input> element child of a <label>
// element with the class-name of, or including, 'active':
var input = document.querySelector('label.active input');

// if the input variable is truthy (not-null in this case):
if (input) {

  // we retrieve the 'name' property from the <input>
  var name = input.name;
  console.log(name); // 'SECOND'
}
```

```js
var input = document.querySelector('label.active input');

if (input) {
  var name = input.name;
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio">Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it's possible to have multiple active `<label>` elements – in the case of check-boxes, for example – then the following would work, to return an array of the `<input>` names:

```
// retrieving a collection of all elements matching the
// supplied selector:
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('label.active input'),

  // converting the array-like collection into an Array,
  // using Array.from():
  inputArray = Array.from(inputs),

  // iterating over the Array using Array.prototype.map(),
  // to return a new Array:
  inputNames = inputArray.map(function(input) {

    // returning the name of the <input> node to
    // the created Array:
    return input.name;
  });

console.log(inputNames); // ['SECOND', 'THIRD']
```

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('label.active input'),
  inputArray = Array.from(inputs),
  inputNames = inputArray.map(function(input) {
    return input.name;
  });

console.log(inputNames);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Property type</label>

  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="FIRST" value="2011" type="radio">HDB
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="SECOND" value="2012" type="radio">Condo / Apt
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input name="THIRD" value="2013" type="radio">Landed
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).